# APEX row selector part 2

Tags: oracle-apex

This is a follow on to "APEX row selector" posted 5 days ago.

The problem was collecting multiple values from an interactive grid.  From the excellent links to post supplied I was able to achieve this.  However, the next part of the project is to open an edit dialog page and update multiple values.

I added this code to the attribute of the interactive grid:

```
    function (config)
{
 var $ = apex.jQuery,
 toolbarData = $.apex.interactiveGrid.copyDefaultToolbar(),
 toolbarGroup = toolbarData.toolbarFind("actions3");
 toolbarGroup.controls.push(
 {
  type: "BUTTON",
  action: "updateCar",
  label: "Edit Selected Cars",
  hot: true,
 });
 config.toolbarData = toolbarData;
 config.initActions = function (actions)
{
  // Defining the action for activate button
  actions.add(
{
  name: "updateCar",
  label: "Edit Selected Cars",
  action: updateCar
 });
}

function updateCar(event, focusElement)
{
 var i, records, model, record,
  view = apex.region("ig_car").widget().interactiveGrid("getCurrentView");

  var vid = "";
  model = view.model;
  records = view.getSelectedRecords();
  if (records.length > 0)
  {
    for (i = 0; i < records.length; i++)
    {
      record = records[i];
                              alert("Under Development " + record[1]);
        vid = vid + record[1] + "||";
        apex.item("P18_CAR").setValue(vid);
   // need to open next page here and pass parameters
    }
  }
}
 return config;
    }
```

I need to know how to open a form and have the parameter values available to pass to an oracle update script.

Thank you for any help you can provide.  I did find some posts but I really need a good example.  I have tried everything to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways you could do this. Here's one way, perhaps someone else will offer a more efficient option.

The JavaScript options for navigation in APEX are documented here:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/aexjs/apex.navigation.html

Since you're trying to open a separate page, you probably want to use `apex.navigation.dialog`, which is what APEX automatically uses when opening modal pages from reports, buttons, etc.

However, as noted in the doc, the URL for the navigation must be generated server-side for security purposes. You need a dynamic URL (one not known when the page renders), so you'll need a workaround to generate it. Once you have the URL, navigating to it is easy. So how do you get the URL? Ajax.

**Create an Ajax process to generate the URL**

1. Under the processing tab of the report/grid page, right-click Ajax Callback and select **Create Process**.
2. Set Name to **GET_FORM_URL**.
3. Set PL/SQL code to the following

code:

```
declare

  l_url varchar2(512);

begin

  l_url := apex_page.get_url(
    p_application => :APP_ID,
    p_page        => 3,
    p_items       => 'P3_ITEM_NAME',
    p_values      => apex_application.g_x01
  );

  apex_json.open_object();
  apex_json.write('url', l_url);
  apex_json.close_object();

end;
```

Note that I'm using `apex_item.get_url` to get the URL, this is an alternative to `apex_util.prepare_url`. I'm also using `apex_json` to emit JSON for the response to the client.

Also, the reference to `apex_application.g_x01` is important, as this will contain the selected values from the calling page. You'll see how this was set in the next step.

**Open the URL with JavaScript**

Enter the following code in the Function and Global Variable Declaration attribute of the calling page:

```
function openFormPage(ids) {
  apex.server.process(
    'GET_FORM_URL', 
    {
      x01: ids.join(':')
    }, 
    {
      success: function (data) {
        var funcBody = data.url.replace(/^"javascript:/, '').replace(/\"$/,'');

        new Function(funcBody).call(window);
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error(errorThrown);
        // handle error
      }
    }
  );

}
```

In this case, I'm using [apex.server.process](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/aexjs/apex.server.html#.process) to call the server-side PL/SQL process. Note that I'm passing the value of `ids.join(':')` to `x01`. That value will become accessible in the PL/SQL code as `apex_application.g_x01`. You can use additional items, or you can pass a colon-delimited string of values to just one item (as I'm doing).

The URL that's returned to the client will not be a standard URL, it will be a JavaScript snippet that includes the URL. You'll need to remove the leading and trailing parts and use what's left to generate a dynamic function in JavaScript.

This is generally frowned upon, but I believe it's safe enough in this context since I know I can trust that the response from the process call is not malicious JavaScript code.

**Add a security check!!!**

Because you're creating a dynamic way to generate URLs to open page 3 (or whatever page you're targeting), you need to ensure that the modal page is protected. On that page, create a Before Header process that validates the value of P3_ITEM_NAME. If the user isn't supposed to be able to access those values, then throw an exception.